# Tensorflow: When to use tf.expand_dims?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow tutorials include the use of `tf.expand_dims` to add a "batch dimension" to a tensor. I have read the docs for this function but it still is rather mysterious to me. Does anyone know exactly under what circumstances this must be used?

My code is below. My intent is to calculate a loss based on the distance between the predicted and actual bins. (E.g. if `predictedBin = 10` and `truthBin = 7` then `binDistanceLoss = 3`).

```py
batch_size = tf.size(truthValues_placeholder)
labels = tf.expand_dims(truthValues_placeholder, 1)
predictedBin = tf.argmax(logits)
binDistanceLoss = tf.abs(tf.sub(labels, logits))
```

In this case, do I need to apply `tf.expand_dims` to `predictedBin` and `binDistanceLoss`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`expand_dims` will not add or reduce elements in a tensor, it just changes the shape by adding `1` to dimensions. For example, a vector with 10 elements could be treated as a 10x1 matrix.

The situation I have met to use `expand_dims` is when I tried to build a ConvNet to classify grayscale images. The grayscale images will be loaded as matrix of size `[320, 320]`. However, `tf.nn.conv2d` require input to be `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`, where the `in_channels` dimension is missing in my data which in this case should be `1`. So I used `expand_dims` to add one more dimension.

In your case, I do not think you need `expand_dims`.

Answer (score 26):

To add to Da Tong's answer, you may want to expand more than one dimension at the same time. For instance, if you are performing TensorFlow's `conv1d` operation on vectors of rank 1, you need to feed them with rank three.

Performing `expand_dims` several times is readable, but might introduce some overhead into the computational graph. You can get the same functionality in a one-liner with `reshape`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# having some tensor of rank 1, it could be an audio signal, a word vector...
tensor = tf.ones(100)
print(tensor.get_shape()) # => (100,)

# expand its dimensionality to fit into conv2d
tensor_expand = tf.expand_dims(tensor, 0)
tensor_expand = tf.expand_dims(tensor_expand, 0)
tensor_expand = tf.expand_dims(tensor_expand, -1)
print(tensor_expand.get_shape()) # => (1, 1, 100, 1)

# do the same in one line with reshape
tensor_reshape = tf.reshape(tensor, [1, 1, tensor.get_shape().as_list()[0],1])
print(tensor_reshape.get_shape()) # => (1, 1, 100, 1)
```

**NOTE:** In case you get the error `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor.`, try to pass `tf.shape(x)[0]` instead of `x.get_shape()[0]` as suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7253).

Hope it helps!
Cheers,
Andres

Comment: Have you run any tests to see whether doing one `reshape` is faster than doing, say, two or three `expand_dims`?

Comment: not really! I took a look into the [sources](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py) but wasn't able to understand where gen_array_ops are, so I can't tell much... would be definitely interested in seeing some tests

Comment: What i really like in this answer is the ability to use a tensor-defined shape and not just a an integer. This really solved my problem, in which i needed in tf.reshape to specify one dimension to be None and the other specified by the current input (batch size was varying) plus already predefined dimensions. The tf.shape(x)[0] within reshape saved the day :) Thanks a lot (even if I didnt ask the question)!

Comment: Glad it helped! and yep, declarative syntax has its quirks :). If you would like to have a more imperative,straightforward flavour but you do need to stick to TF you may want to take a look at the recently added [eager API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager). There are other alternatives, most notably PyTorch. I did recently [a review on DL platforms](https://github.com/andres-fr/dl-frameworks/blob/master/latex-presentation/dl-frameworks-presentation.pdf), feel free to take a look and provide feedback if you want. Cheers