# tensorflow conv1d & max_pool for 1-d data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use tensorflow to create a CNN (convnet) for application on a 1-d dataset.  My data is structured as rows of floats, with an associated one-hot target for each ( feature1 , feature2 ... feature100 ; y_val )

I've run it through a basic multi-layer perceptron, but want to exploit 'localities' in the feature space, as well as take advantage of 'downsampling' of the feature space through pooling, etc.

The issue is that I *cannot* find any way to do this with tensorflow -
 either the conv1d or conv2d functions - which deliver the error

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'conv1d_4/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes
```

things only get worse when I try to create pooling layers.

My question is: Has anyone done a 1-d CNN in tensorflow?  If so, could you point me to some code samples so I can get a more concrete understanding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is as the error suggests that the shape of your input doesn't match that which is required by tensorflow's convolution function. You can do one-dimensional convolution using `tf.nn.conv1d` (you can refer the docs here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d). `tf.nn.conv1d()` takes input in the form of batches, so even if you're feeding a single value, it expects the batch dimension. Thus your input data should have the form [a,b,c]  where:

- a is the batch dimension(If you've divided your input dataset into n batches, then this tells you which batch the input can be found in )
- b is the number of input channels(In case you input is in RGB you can give 3, else 1)
- c is the length of each input sequence

What this function essentially does is it reshapes your input from [a,b,c] to [a,1,b,c] and feeds it to the `tf.nn.conv2d()` function. 
You can follow this same principle while trying to max_pool - i.e. reshape your input using `tf.reshape()` into 2-d and then reshape it back to 1-d.

Comment: That is the way I do it. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555035/4511978) I posted code examples for arbitrary reshaping, hope it helps someone, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can try [tf.layers.max_pooling1d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/max_pooling1d).

It supports 3-rank inputs which has the format of `(batch, length, channels)`. Or you can specify your own format with `data_format` parameter.

And it supports the output of `tf.layers.conv1d`.