# ERROR: cannot import name 'squeeze_or_expand_dimensions'

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d,max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data,dropout,fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
```

[Snippet of the code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRcp4.png

I used tensorflow==1.13.2,1.4,1.5,2.0
But still the error persists.

Actually while I tried importing tflearn and tensorflow, it throws the same error
ModuleNotFoundError:

> No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of giving a screenshot of your code/error, write it directly there.

Secondly you should have told  us your librairies version.

Mine :

- tensorflow==2.1
- keras==2.2.4

I checked the file losses_utils, there is apparently no function called :

> `squeeze_or_expend_dims`

i don't know why you need them but this might help you :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10,10))
print(a.shape)

a=np.expand_dims(a,axis=0)
print(a.shape)

a=np.squeeze(a, axis=0)
print(a.shape)

#(10,10)
#(1,10,10)
#(10,10)
```

In addition if you want to use a built-in function from tensorflow
use :

> tf.expand_dims and tf.squeeze
> See this post for more info [Tensorflow: When use tf.expand_dims?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008821/tensorflow-when-use-tf-expand-dims)